# Tempdata null after redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to use TempData to record a boolean value in the case of failed authorization but whenever I try to actually access it, it is still shown as null. My code is this:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult FailedAuth()
    {
        TempData["failed"] = true;
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Index");
    }
```

I use the FailedAuth action from an authorize attribute but after the redirect TempData remains null, even when I use TempData.Keep(). I've tried to use Session as well, to no avail. I simply want to display an error message on the page to indicate a failed authorization, is there a way to make this work? Or a different way to do it? 
Thanks

*Edit:
So, tracing through each step I see that tempdata is set properly in failedauth, then returns to where it was called in the authorize attribute with 
filterContext.Result = (new IndexController()).FailedAuth();
then aftwards goes back to the controller and runs the index() method, with tempdata now at null.

Comment: there is no need to use keep method. it must work true. try to trace your program more carefully. maybe i can help you with seeing more info about your project.

Comment: I edited the post to include my results from tracing it

Comment: try to use another name instead of 'failed'. maybe there is a name conflict.

Comment: Are your web servers behind a load balancer by chance?

Comment: No luck with changing the name. This is all hosted locally at the moment.